# How to appropriately treat the assembly on the package folder when check in to the TeamFoundationServer at VisualStudio.com?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tfs

I was creating ASP.NET MVC 5 web app and put it in the Team Foundation Server source code control (visualstudio.com). There is a folder named "packages" that contains all assembly I've got thru nugget. After a while, I need to create another app, and I use TFS to get latest version of my code from TFS. But all the references to the third parties assemblies that point to the folder "packages" seems to have some problem. The icons has yellow triangle with exclamation point for each assembly. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because NuGet just creates the folder with referenced packages but it doesn't add it to your source control. Why don't you just add the folder NuGet created to your solution and that way it will become a part of your project in TFS?

That way your TFS server will have all the required packages and will be able to copy the packages to your new solution or if you try to open the solution on another computer.